# Data Converting into Collection Tileset Instead of Type (Line) Tileset in Mapbox Studio

Tags: mapbox

A recent issue I've encountered with Mapbox Studio is the apparent inability to upload a geojson as anything other than a collection tileset, instead of a point, line, or polygon tileset. For example, the old tileset (circled in black) shows the line icon where the new one (circled in blue) shows the collection icon.

[image: Screenshot of Tileset Selection]

My difficulty lies in updating the style. When I go to switch out the data Mapbox Studio detects the different data type and resets the style...which means I have to style that layer by hand each time I update the information. This becomes time consuming when the tileset is used on 15+ layers. So far Mapbox's response has been to "update the style" which is not helpful as that's what I'm trying to do.

I put the geojson into a text editor to remove "feature collection" and just make it a list of features, but Mapbox won't upload it and errors out. I created a dataset directly in Studio but when exported to a tileset the same thing happens (becomes a collection instead of line). I have also tried this with data that contained a single polygon or a single point and encounter the same issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I tried adjusting the data so maybe the issue is in learning how to save the styling information or preventing the style from clearing when a different data type is detected?

Comment: You're not the only one who's noticed this. Your best bet is reaching out to Mapbox Support about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox has resolved the bug. I had entered a help ticket with them about this and they were able to recreate the issue. But it's fixed now.